# Vim powerline doesn't show the current branch

Tags: vim, git

I'm using the vim plugin called powerline and it isn't showing the git branch I'm on, while it's supposed to be activated by default. The fugitive plugin is installed, though I don't think it was required. Is there anything else I'm supposed to do for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Try running `:PowerlineClearCache`. The branch is not activated by default.

Answer (score 2):

you should have [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) installed, if you have it already and yet it does not show, and `:PowerlineClearCache` doesn't help then try removing `Powerline_default_default_compatible.cache` from powerline `plugin` folder and restarting vim.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the `let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'` option works well (the array symbol and the LN symbol are displayed normally as in the screenshot) then try running `:PowerlineClearCache` in any vim session then restart your vim. Or you should patch your font first.